# Combining 2 Select queries using dates and then Joining 2 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried to join my queries, but I get stuck on the Sunday time,

I have a very basic and straight forward join query, to calculate all the hours worked by employees, normal time and overtime and the query works perfectly, but when I want to join the Sunday time, it all goes haywire...

Full query without Sunday time:-

```
SELECT
`empl_attendance`.`employee_id`,
`employee`.`employee_surname`,
`employee`.`employee_first_name`,
`employee`.`employee_second_name`,
FORMAT((IF(SUM...some basic maths...)),1) AS nt,
FORMAT((...some basic maths...),1) AS ot,
FORMAT((...some basic maths...),1) AS total
FROM
`empl_attendance`
WHERE
 (`empl_attendance_date` BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date')
INNER JOIN 
`employee` 
ON `empl_attendance`.`employee_id`=`employee`.`employee_id` 
GROUP BY `employee_id`
```

But I need to combine the following query, which basically calculates the total Sunday hours of each employee. The query works fine on its own, I am only struggling to combine the two queries:

```
SELECT SUM(`empl_attendance_total`) AS sundays
FROM `empl_attendance`
WHERE
(`empl_attendance_date` BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date')
AND
WEEKDAY(`empl_attendance_date`) > 5
GROUP BY `employee_id`
```

Thanx

Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a case statement:

```
 SELECT  ea.`employee_id`, e.`employee_surname`,  e.`employee_first_name`,  e.`employee_second_name`,
         FORMAT((IF(SUM...some basic maths...)),1) AS nt,
         FORMAT((...some basic maths...),1) AS ot,
         FORMAT((...some basic maths...),1) AS total,
         sum(case when weekday(ea.empl_attendance_date) > 5 then ea.empl_attendance_total end) as SundayTotal
 FROM empl_attendance ea join
      employee e
      ON ea.`employee_id = e.employee_id
  WHERE  ea.empl_attendance_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'
  GROUP BY `employee_id`
```

I am assuming that the lines starting with FORMAT are looking for the non-Sunday dates, or at least including them, if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanx a million @Gordon Linoff it works perfectly. Thank you for the help, I now see where I went wrong.